# Just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to get drivers installed for wireless USB adaptor

Tags: wireless, 16.04, d-link

I'm unsure how this OS really works but I'm having a hard time finding information on installing drivers. Coming over from using Windows.

Where can I find those drivers and how can I install them properly?

Comment: Can you give us more information about your wifi adapter?

Comment: its a d-link dwa 171 usb adaptor

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is:

1. find out what chip is used in your adapter.
2. find the source code for a driver and compile it.
3. use modprobe to install the module into the kernel.
4. use dkms to allow the source code to be built when the kernel updates.

To that end:

1. open terminal and type `lsusb`

   look for an entry that shows your D-Link, like such:

   Bus 002 Device 010: ID 2001:3314 D-Link Corp.

   the 2001:3314 is the vendor:device ID

   Google 2001:3314

   one of the results will take you here:
    https://wikidevi.com/wiki/D-Link_DWA-171_rev_A1
    look at the right side of the page and it'll identify a driver.
2. download the driver and compile it with "make".
3. if there are no compiler errors, use "modprobe" to load the kernel
   module, and test your device now.
4. install "dkms" and learn how to make it so that the module will rebuild
   automatically when Ubuntu updates the kernel software.

Comment: This does not even compile for me!

Comment: You may have gotten a driver that's too old for your newer kernel. Did you check your device ID? If it matches my instructions, you may need to use https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.

Comment: I installed that via `dkms`. My computer now finds the hotspots around me, but I cannot connect to any... It just keeps connecting and disconnecting. Any ideas on how to debug this, please?

Comment: @Victor Try turning off power management for that adapter. Also, are you using WPA2-AES?

Comment: What power management are you talking about? I am on a desktop at the office. I don't know what security model the router is using, but others have the exact same adapter and it works for them on windows.

Comment: `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`. Change wlan0 to the correct adapter name. You can't compare Windows connectivity to Ubuntu connectivity... they do things differently.